# Gerar chaves de 9 dígitos com Python

Tags: python, array

Gostaria de gerar diversos valores seguindo o padrão `XXX-XXX-XXX` onde será gerado todas as possibilidades por exemplo:

```
1 - 000-000-000
2 - 000-000-001
3 - 000-000-002
.
.
.
x - 999-999-999
.
.
.
x - 000-000-00A
x - 000-000-00B
.
.
.
x - A8S-71J-8SH
.
.
.
x - ZZZ-ZZZ-ZZZ
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer este código para que siga o padrão proposto?

Comment: Só é válido letras e números? Letras minúsculas não, nem pontuações?

Comment: Sim @AndersonCarlosWoss somente números e letras maiúsculas sem pontuação só mesmo preenchendo os valores de X em XXX-XXX-XXX

Comment: você tem uma resposta certa, para uma tarefa que com quase toda a chance é completamente inútil. VOcê está falando de mais de  5 trilhões de combinações - nenhum dispositivo ordinário pode sequer aramazenar todas (embora seja possível hoje em dia com um data center dedicado, acredito). Mesmo que você não queira armazenar, o Python vai poder gerar algumas milhões dessas por segundo - você levaria cerca de 10 dias pra gerar todas num PC comum  - a náo ser que você esteja fazendo um brute-force para tentar achar a chave de dados estáticos que tenha em mãos, está fazendo errado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `combinations` do modulo `itertools`

```
import itertools
import string

for row in itertools.combinations(string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase, 9):
  s = ''.join(row)
  print('{}-{}-{}'.format(s[:3], s[3:6], s[6:9]))
```

Comment: Bem pontuado... Obrigado ! Edit: Se não concatenar a string, a saída será 3 tuplas.